# Unable to run docker image created from ISO

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

Here i am trying to create docker image from ubuntu 14.04 ISO file, knowing ubuntu 14.04 is already available in docker hub. Because later i have to create docker images for Suse10 and Suse11[sp1 64bit] which is not available in docker hub.

I was able to create docker image from ubuntu 14.04 ISO with below commands

```
# mkdir rootfs
# mount -o loop /path/to/iso rootfs
# tar -C rootfs -c . | docker import - newubuntu
```

With above image gets successfully created , i can do `docker images` it gets listed

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker images
```

> REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED
>   VIRTUAL SIZE
>
> newubuntu              latest              1dcd1b632d37        5 days
>   ago          1.015 GB

But when i try to run image, then i get below error message

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker run -t -i newubuntu /bin/bash
```

> 2015/03/11 06:59:16 exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or
>   directory

**Please kindly let me know  how to resolve this error. I should be able to create container from that image and install other applications.**

Answer (score 3):

You're building an image from ubuntu's iso but what you really want is building an image from an ubuntu install.

What you have to do is :

- install ubuntu from the iso inside a VM
- make an archive of the VM's / (this can be done with `cd / && tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /`)
- import with docker (this can be done with `docker import /path/to/your/backup.tar.gz`)

I hope that helps

Comment: Hi @xav19, do you have a more complete description of what you describe? (any your answer does help.  Thanks)

Comment: Hi @robert-lugg!The author of the initial question tries to create a docker image from an installation ISO. But a docker image is an image of an **installed** system, not an image of a installation CD/ISO. If you only have an installation ISO, install it in a VM, make a tar.gz of the root filesystem of the VM (cd/ &&  tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /), export hte archive on your host system and import it inside docker (docker import /path/to/your/backup.tar.gz). It should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @xav19.  That is great.  I was worried about "capturing" everything in / but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use debootstrap to install a base image (you may include and exclude packages) into a directory that is chrootable.

You can use that directory to create the base image.