# Build your own OS Docker image, i.e. from scratch and from ISO

Tags: docker, operating-system, iso

**Scenario:**

From "Docker Desktop for Windows" I want to build a initial (base) image based on a ISO Linux downloaded from official website.

Documentation here and there on how to do it is quite sparse: I feel like this should be achieve with "FROM scratch" and "docker import" commands but things are quite confusing as there is no clear procedure as a whole, and no examples.

I have been searching over Google and stackoverflow for quite a bit now, and either I did not manage to use the right keywords or no one already faced this scenario. (I know most people tend to build over base images as they are focused on applications developments rather than operating systems.)

Still, I believe some people know how to do it because this how we get alpine, ubuntu, debian and other docker base images! Which is what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will be able to explain things clearly with some example, say elementaryOS.

**Precisions:**

While still trying to find clues, I have found these similar questions on Stackoverflow:

- [#42385527](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385527/how-to-create-docker-image-from-an-iso-file)
- [#28980512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980512/unable-to-run-docker-image-created-from-iso)

There is not clear answer though.

**References (documentation):**

- [Create a base image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/)
- [docker import command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/)

Comment: Something like the [`alpine` Dockerfile](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/410e490d5b140378624dc7c1c740c94462d8d6d3/x86_64/Dockerfile) is pretty typical – start `FROM scratch` and unpack a distribution tarball into it.  Is there a specific problem you're having?  Is this about building an application, or just understanding how Linux is put together?

Comment: @DavidMaze No specific problem here. Just trying to understand how to build an OS image as we may consider building our own OS specific image in my company for various reasons, and from there developers will be able to use it as a base for all their apps. The thing is I'm starting from a ISO image, not a tarball. The ISO seems have nothing in common with the tarball "OS installed fs" because it seems I'm a step before: OS is packed and probably require installation(?).

Answer (score -2):

You are better off using the official distribution Docker images (e.g. [https://hub.docker.com/*/ubuntu*](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu), [https://hub.docker.com//debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian), https://hub.docker.com/_/centos, etc.). There's a base image for elementaryOS too: https://hub.docker.com/r/elementary/docker

Why?

1. A Linux distribution installed via the ISO installer will by default boot into something like `systemd`, which isn't what you want in a container where you're typically only running one server.
2. The base Docker images are usually configured in other ways for the container environment. E.g. disabling `fsync()` on package installs, which makes for faster image builds and is fine in typical container workloads where packages are only installed at image build time.

Comment: I do understand the reasons for using official images but this is not what I need. I'm trying to understand how to make mine, starting from point zero where you only have that ISO image you usually end up in installing in a partition. Do you have any clue on how build an OS image like they did for ubuntu, centos, etc.?

Comment: Here's what Debian uses: https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look =)